# Get low level xpath from XML with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm trying to store in an array all the unique Xpaths of the low level elements in the XML below, but like I'm doing in array a is being stored all the XML, not only the Xpath themselves. The XML has different levels of Xpath. I mean, some child elements only have 2 ancestors and others more than one.

This is the code I have.

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <name>Cake</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <batters>
            <batter>Regular</batter>
            <batter>Chocolate</batter>
            <batter>Blueberry</batter>
            <batter>Devil's Food</batter>
        </batters>
        <topping>None</topping>
        <topping>Glazed</topping>
        <topping>Sugar</topping>
        <topping>Powdered Sugar</topping>
        <topping>Chocolate with Sprinkles</topping>
        <topping>Chocolate</topping>
        <topping>Maple</topping>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Raised</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <batters>
            <batter>Regular</batter>
        </batters>
        <topping>None</topping>
        <topping>Glazed</topping>
        <topping>Sugar</topping>
        <topping>Chocolate</topping>
        <topping>Maple</topping>
    </item>
</items>
EOT

a = []
a = doc.xpath("//*")

puts a
```

I'd like to store in array "a" only the unique xpaths as below:

```
/items/item/name
/items/item/ppu
/items/item/batters/batter
/items/item/topping
```

Maybe somebody could help me in how to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly do you want to store? The XPath itself or the contents of the elements?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to select is the "leaf" nodes. You can do it like so:

```
doc.xpath("//*[not(*)]")
```

This means "select all elements that don't contain elements".

If you want the XPaths, you'll need to call `.path` on each node. But the paths provided by Nokogiri have explicit positions (e.g. `/items/item[2]/topping[4]`), so you'll have to apply a regex to remove them, then remove duplicates with `uniq`:

```
doc.xpath("//*[not(*)]").map {|leaf| leaf.path.gsub(/\[.*?\]/, '') }.uniq
```

Output:

```
/items/item/name
/items/item/ppu
/items/item/batters/batter
/items/item/topping
```

Comment: Hello Mark. Excellent answer. Thanks a lot. There are several concepts mixed in your answer (ruby methods, regex, xpath, etc). I didn't know that the correct name is leaf nodes. Thank you for the clarification. Do you know a good link where can I see the options for Xpath? I didn't know the existence and meaning of the option you used "[not(*)]". Thanks again

Comment: Cute *xpath* expression it is.

Comment: @Zurix There's a good [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) at W3Schools. Specifically, the `[]` is a *predicate* which further constrains an expression, and `not()` is an XPath *function* which returns a boolean, in this case it returns false if there are any child elements (`*`)

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but you may want to think of the XPath `//*[not(*)]` as equivalent to the Ruby pseudocode `elements.select{|el| el.child_elements.empty?}`

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation and help provided Mark. Much appreaciated.

Comment: Helo Mark, should I have to accept your answer doing click somewhere or how? I'm kind of new in stackoverflow. Thanks